# Access Microsoft Graph API in Django Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, microsoft-graph-api, python-3.10

I have a Django project that uses [django-microsoft-auth](https://github.com/AngellusMortis/django_microsoft_auth) for user authentication and I would like to know how I could go about get users' profile pictures from the Microsoft Graph API if they are logged in.

I know from the documentation that I need to use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value to get the picture data then I can encode it as Base64 then I can use a context processor to pass it to my base.html template and put it in an image as seen in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032759/get-user-profile-picture-in-microsoft-graph). What I don't know how to do is implement getting the data from the API. I know I need an access token, but I'm not sure how to get that since all of the authentication is handled by the django-microsoft-aith package.

Comment: Here is the Microsoft Graph sample Python web app using the Django application: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-pythondjangoapp#microsoft-graph-sample-python-web-app

Comment: @MehtabSiddique I've already seen the example, I would like to know how to integrate the Graph API without reimplementing the authentication that is already handled by django-microsoft-auth.

Comment: I came across the question tangentially to an issue I'm working on. Maybe you could use https://github.com/O365/python-o365?